# Can I execute multiple catch blocks that correspond to one try block?

Tags: c#, java

Consider I have a try block that contains 3 statements, and all of them cause Exceptions. I want all the 3 exceptions to be handled by their relevant catch blocks.. is it possible ?

something like this-->

```
class multicatch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] c={1};
        String s="this is a false integer";
        try
        {
            int x=5/args.length;
            c[10]=12;
            int y=Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException ae)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot divide a number by zero.");
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException abe)
        {
            System.out.println("This array index is not accessible.");
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot parse a non-integer string.");
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to obtain the following output? -->>

```
Cannot divide a number by zero.
This array index is not accessible.
Cannot parse a non-integer string.
```

Comment: Do you think such a log message would be of any help at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to obtain the following output?

No, because only one of the exceptions will be thrown. Execution leaves the `try` block as soon as the exception is thrown, and assuming there's a matching `catch` block, it continues there. It doesn't go back into the `try` block, so you can't end up with a second exception.

See the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) for a general lesson in exception handling, and [section 11.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch multiple exceptions, you have to split your code across multiple try/catch blocks.

A better approach is to validate your data and log errors without triggering Exceptions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Jon's answer, while you won't catch multiple exceptions from a single `try` block, you can have multiple handlers handle a single exception.

```
try
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("This is an exception.");
    }
    catch(Exception foo)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(foo.Message);
        throw; // rethrows foo for the next handler.
    }
}
catch(Exception bar)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("And again: " + bar.Message);
}
```

This produces the output:

```
This is an exception.
And again: This is an exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a REALY BAD PRACTICE, but you can do next (solve your problem using `finally` block):

```
private static void Main()
        {
            int[] c={1};
            String s="this is a false integer";
            try
            {
                int z = 0;
                int x = 5/z;
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.GetType().ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    c[10] = 12;
                }
                catch(IndexOutOfRangeException exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception.GetType().ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int y = int.Parse(s);
                    }
                    catch (FormatException exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exception.GetType().ToString());
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing all of the exceptions handling at once is impossible. The goal of each exception `catch` is to have a different handling for each `Exception` type and otherwise it's pointless to print them all together.

Answer (score 0):

> No ,

It will not execute all three catch statements. The **TRY** block checks for error and then the execution comes out of the TRY block. Then **Suitable** catch  will be executed. In your case, The **ArithmeticException** is in the Top of the Exception Hierarchy. So it will Execute and then the program terminates.

If you give, **Catch(Exception e)** before **ArithmeticException** then Exception catch will be executed... Better read about the SystemException Hierarchies at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.systemexception(v=vs.110).aspx)